# Renderscript Allocation Crashes

Tags: android, c++, renderscript

Can not understand because when I try to use the Allocation both as input and ouput, the program crashes.

I've checked if due to some type of permission in the android manifest, but neither.

**The project.properties is as follows:**

```
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=20.0.0
```

**The code is as follows:**

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Allocation inputAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(r, bmp, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

...
```

**And the logcat shows me the following errors:**

```
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpurenderscript/com.example.gpurenderscript.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation.createFromBitmap(Allocation.java:1337)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation.createFromBitmap(Allocation.java:1388)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.example.gpurenderscript.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-25 11:32:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line:

`options.inJustDecodeBounds = true`

This is setting up the `BitmapFactory` with the sizing information for your bitmap, but the `decodeResource()` method is actually return null as there was no memory allocated for the backing pixels, so no `Bitmap` object.  You need to have the backing pixels in order for the `Allocation` to actually be created so it can marshall the data between Java and RenderScript.